# iterator() method automatically invoke

Tags: java, collections

Im new to Collection java, and sorry if the questions are so basic.

While debugging a piece of codes in Shipment class. If return value in `iterator()` is `null` the test case is failed, but if returning values is `products.iterator` the test case is passed. So, I supposed that the iterator() method is automatically invoked when running the `hasItem()` in ShipmentTest class. But the strange is that it was invoked without calling from test file, like normal code

```
Iterator itr = al.iterator();

      while(itr.hasNext()) {
         Object element = itr.next();
         // do something....
      }
```

and the return type of `hasItem()` not return values related to iterator...

Anyone has experienced this case, can help share your ideas?

Here are the codes:

ShipmentTest class

```java
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.core.IsCollectionContaining.hasItem;

public class ShipmentTest {

    private Shipment shipment = new Shipment();
    Product door = new Product("Door", 22);
    Product windows = new Product("Windows", 10);

    @Test
    public void shouldAddItems() throws Exception {
        shipment.add(door);
        shipment.add(windows);

        assertThat(shipment, hasItem(door));
    }
}
```

Shipment class

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class Shipment implements Iterable<Product> {

    private static final int LIGHT_VAN_MAX_WEIGHT = 20;
    private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public Iterator<Product> iterator() {
        return products.iterator();
    }

    public void add(Product p) {
        products.add(p);
    }
}
```

Product class

```java
public class Product {

    private final String name;
    private final int weight;

    public Product(String name, int weight) {
        this.name = name;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", weight=" + weight +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in order to test whether a collection contains an item, `IsCollectionContaining.hasItem` calls `iterator()`. That's a perfectly normal part of dealing with any `Iterable`. (How else *could* it tell whether the shipment contains a particular item?)

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer. As the *natural implementation of Java*, when an Iterable method `hasItem()` is called, it will find the implemented `iterator()` in the called class `Shipment`. If the `iterator()` is existing, it return the corresponding value, if not it throw error ? Is that correct

Comment: @LearningandWorking: The `hasItem()` method isn't part of Java - it's just a method in Hamcrest, and the `iterator()` method *has* to exist, otherwise the call to `hasItem` would fail at compile time, as you can only call it on a matcher where the type implements `Iterable<T>`.